# Wrap application deployables in Docker Image

Tags: deployment, docker, production-environment

I'd like to make the deployment to production the easiest it can be, but struggling with the way how to do it.

If I will have docker for production, it will be nice to have docker image with my application deployables, but I'm not sure if it is good approach.

I have several concerns:

1. wouldn't the layer system bloat, when I will replace the file every time in new version of image?
2. Is it good idea to make DB scripts and migration tool part of this image?
3. The last concern is how to run it conveniently. I don't want to go there stop the tomcat container and start it again using volume from new application image(as the new app container name cannot be the same).

I have seen ways to do that, but I don't like them very much i.e. deploy to Tomcat docker image ,create Tomcat image with application already bundled or use host system volume. I like to have something like install "CD". I'd like to evaluate my idea with other approaches, speaking about the proper tool to run it is maybe for other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> wouldn't the layer system bloat, when I will replace the file every time in new version of image?

No because you can [clean up dangling images](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/bb0a9afb4195da083e77157d54cb626d1b9eaa1d/.bash_aliases#L22)

```
docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)
```

> Is it good idea to make DB scripts and migration tool part of this image?

Yes, if your startup script knows to detect if it needs to apply them.

> I don't like them very much i.e. deploy to Tomcat docker image ,create Tomcat image with application already bundled or use host system volume.

If your data volume container is separate from the app, that shouldn't be an issue.

From [the discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91385/discussion-between-zveratko-and-vonc), the OP adds:

> using this `docker create --name <container_name> <image_name>` with different image name can retain the container name and I can run Tomcat container with the same volumes-from?

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8080 --volumes-from <container_name> <image_name>
```

That is the idea, but it won't work if there is already a create data container with that name.

If there is no persistent data in it, one can docker rm that data container, and recreate it with the same name.

If there are persistent data, then it is best to copy the new updated data through an intermediate (`docker run`) container which would mount temporarily the data container.

Comment: Sorry for maybe stupid question, but my Tomcat container needs to know from which container it is using the deployables. If I will create new container with app 1.1, I will not be able to name the container the same name and link with it using --volumes-from <container_name>. So I will at least need to replace the data-volume name for Tomcat container, right?

Comment: @Zveratko a data-volume container contains data, no app, so the version doesn't apply here, and its name never change.

Comment: But this is what I want do have, plain Tomcat container and have it use another container (data-only) which holds the application binaries(this one will be versioned /tagged according to application version). It will need a little bit more orchestration, but I think it is pretty legal approach, isn't it?

Comment: @Zveratko it is, but when you create your data container, you can give it a fixed name, and use that one with your tomcat container.

Comment: but then I will need to replace its content. I mean put in the proper binaries. I asking about wrapping the binaries inside image. So then I will have docker image for each application release.

Comment: @Zveratko you can have a docker image for each version, but if that image is used as a data volume container (because it has a VOLUME directive in its Dockerfile), then the data container that you create from the latest tag of that image can keep a fixed name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91385/discussion-between-zveratko-and-vonc).

Comment: @Zveratko I have included the conclusion of your discussion in the answer for more visibility.